# best practices to minimize garbage collection hiccups in Go

Tags: go, garbage-collection

The below article talks about minimizing garbage collection. Are there any best practices from a programmers perspective to make garbage collection efficient in Go?

[How to minimize the garbage collection in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277426/how-to-minimize-the-garbage-collection-in-go)

Comment: Yes: Do not produce garbage. How? Measure your allocations and get rid of the most ugly ones.

Comment: @Volker this is the answer in Go fashion :)

Comment: What exactly is your question, since you're linking to the same question which already has multiple answers?

Comment: For example, does it help to allocate contiguous blocks of memory, allocate bigger chunks upfront, or reduce the number different variables created in order to make garbage collection go faster?

Comment: The only thing that really helps is: Measure it.

Answer (score 0):

"[how to analyse golang memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865558/6309)" gives some criteria, but the best approach remains to measure:

- "[Visualising the Go garbage collector](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/07/11/visualising-the-go-garbage-collector)"
- "[Garbage Collector Trace](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Performance#garbage-collector-trace)": `GODEBUG=gctrace=1 ./myserver`